# Работа с базой Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Создаю виджет на yii2.

```
<?php

namespace common\widgets;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class Blog_index extends Widget
{
    public $db;
    $db = Yii::$app->db;
    public $posts = $db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM user u, post p WHERE u.id=p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC')->queryAll();


    public function run()
    {
        return $this->posts['content'];
    }
}
?>
```

Выводит ошибку:

[image: Что здесь неправильно?]

Все перепробовал, не получается.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь присвоить значение БД вне метода.... вы вначале сделали его строкой... а ниже сразу пытаетесь присаваивать значение..... вам это надо минимум делать в методе `init`.....то есть `public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->db = Yii::$app->db;
    }` ....... и инициализируйте `$db` тогда уж не строкой а `null`... так логичнее, вам не кажется? ` public $db = null;` ..........вы в какой **IDE** работаете можно узнать?

Comment: Спасибо! Да надо было null

Comment: brackets_______

Comment: Неужели вам `IDE` не подсказывает, что у вас ошибки? Или вы игнорите все предупреждения? ..... и просто установив `$db = null` ошибку не исправить......как я написал выше... нужно в init переносить инициализацию как DB так и $posts

Comment: я так и сделал. content тоже нужно объявлять? а то выводит ошибку Undefined index: content

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь объявлять `$db` строкой, а ниже опять пытаетесь объявить свойство с тем же именем, но инициализируя её `Yii-$app->db`. Конечно, как минимум, ругается на то, что уже есть такая переменная.

Надо все переменные необходимые объявить, а произвести инициализацию в методе `init()` при необходимости.  Всё остальное делать в методе `run()`.

Вот как должно всё выглядеть:

```
<?php

namespace common\widgets;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Widget;
use yii\helpers\Html;

class Blog_index extends Widget {

    public $db = null;
    public $posts = [];


    public function init() {
        parent::init();
        $this->db = Yii::$app->db;  
    }


    public function run() {
      $this->posts = $this->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM user u, post p WHERE u.id=p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC')->queryAll();

      return $this->render('widgetTemplateName', ['posts' => $this->posts['content']]);  //  return $this->render('widgetTemplateName', ['posts' => $this->posts]);     
    }
}
?>
```

Т.к. виджет - это что-то видимое (на то он и виджет), то он должен что-то рендерить, какой-то темплейт, а не просто возвращать данные в вакуум, как  у вас

Comment: Я уже стесняюсь задавать вопросы. Ну опять же ругается на content. Может изза того что не подключил класс для работы с БД?

Comment: А что есть контент? Переменная какая или что? И где ругается? в шаблоне или где? Если в шаблоне, то как выводите?

Comment: Все заработал. Оказывается sql запрос у меня неправильный был. Спасибо большое